# conditional rendering using ngIf in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onReceipeList()">Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="onShoppingList()">Shopping List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})


export class HeaderComponent {
  // now call the methods 
  @Output()receipeClick=true;
  @Output()shoppingClick=true;

  onReceipeList(){
    console.log("we are inside Receipe List")
    this.receipeClick=false;
  }

  onShoppingList(){
    console.log("we are inside shooping click")
    this.shoppingClick=false;
  }
}
```

app-component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes *ngIf="!receipeClick"></app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list *ngIf="!shoppingClick"></app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1)i want to render my code conditionally

2)Whenever the user click the header component i am listing to click event and trigring a method which inturn changing  the bollenType in my code and exporting as output

3)Inturn i am listing to that expression so the list

but my code is not working i don't know why

Comment: Define "not working". Tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: nothing is shown in console as well the page is same as before no change is made in the gui

Comment: We don't know what is was before, and what changes you expect from before. Be precise: what are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Your app component view tries to use variables that don't exist in the AppCOmponet class. They exist in the HeaderComponent. You can't do that. And you also need to read the documentation about Output, because your code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no need to declare as `Output` properties:

```
@Output()receipeClick=true;
@Output()shoppingClick=true;
```

as they are used just as variables. So change to:

```
receipeClick = true;
shoppingClick = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html

```
<app-header (receipeClick)="updatereceipeClick($event)" (shoppingClick)="updatereceipeClick($event)">
</app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-recipes *ngIf="!receipeClick"></app-recipes>
      <app-shopping-list *ngIf="!shoppingClick"></app-shopping-list>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
receipeClick = true;
shoppingClick = true;

updatereceipeClick(val) {
    this.receipeClick = val;
  }
updateshoppingClick(val) {
    this.shoppingClick = val;
  }
```